# What is this metal box with BNC connectors for?

Tags: rf, identification, resistance, coax

I found this box with a schematic drawn on it.  What is it for?

[image]

Comment: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/attenuators/attenuator.html

Comment: Apparently somebody needed a 101:1 attenuator with no impedance matching. As to what for, who can tell?

Comment: Something somebody built themselves; not a COTs product.

Comment: Merlin Gerin were a manufacturer of mains voltage and above circuit protection components, so a roughly 100:1 divider for a scope or spectrum analyser is the sort of thing that I could seen being in their labs.

Comment: And the box is a standard one from Pomona Electronics

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an attenuator with coax inputs, no input match, and an output impedance of approximately 50 ohms. Based on the coax inputs and 50-ohm output impedance, it looks like it might be designed for high-speed or RF use as part of a 50-ohm system.

By applying the equations for a resistor divider and Thevenin impedance it's clear that when an ideal voltage is applied to the right port then approximately 0.01 times that voltage (so around 40 dB attenuation) is output to the left port, with an output impedance of *approximately* 50 ohms (so approximately a match for a 50-ohm transmission line).

Note that the right side does not have an impedance match to 50 ohms, so high speed signals may reflect off of it. An alternative design that provides an input match on that side could be, for example, a pi network made as follows which provides a 50-ohm impedance to both sides and a 40 dB attenuation:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fgSiC6.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that such a network would be driven from the right using a 50-ohm-terminated source, not an ideal voltage source.

Answer (score 6):

Merlin Gerin (now called [Schneider Electric](https://www.se.com/uk/en/about-us/company-profile/brands/merlin-gerin.jsp)) is a manufacturer of mains electric switchgear. So this attenuator may be built into a box with BNC connectors for convenient connection to test equipment, e.g. oscilloscopes, at mains frequency (50/60 Hz) rather than RF. Hence the lack of an impedance matched input.

I'd remove the cover and check the power rating of whatever makes up the 5 kΩ resistor to work out a safe operating voltage. Operation at 120 V would require a rather optimistic 3 W power rating (though it might use power resistors bolted to the case for cooling). 240 V operation would require an unlikely 12 W power handling. (Actual use shouldn't exceed 50% of the maximum power rating.)